# How to test a custom doctrine hydrator in ZF2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine, phpunit

In order to add some additional (filtering) functionality to the `DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject` I extended it and created the class `EntityHydrator`:

```
namespace MyLib\Model\Entity\Hydrator;

class EntityHydrator extends \DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject
{
    protected $foo;
    protected $bar;

    public function __construct(
        \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager $objectManager,
        $byValue = true,
        $foo = true
    ) {
        parent::__construct($objectManager, $byValue);
        $this->setFoo($foo);
    }

    public function extract($object)
    {
        $extractedArray = parent::extract($object);
        $extractedArray = $this->getFoo()
            ? $this->performAdditionalFunctionality($extractedArray)
            : $extractedArray
        ;
        return $extractedArray;
    }

    // access methods for $foo and $bar

    // private/protected methods like performAdditionalFunctionality(...) and other
}
```

Now the class should get unit tested. The problem is the testing of the `extract(...)`. This method is based on the `\DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject#extract(...)`. That means I need an `EntityHydrator`/`DoctrineObject` -- with all its dependencies. What is the best way to handle this and get a custom (doctrine) hydrator unit-tested?

Comment: Why would want to test DoctrineObject, you goal should be test your functionality alone right?

Comment: Right, but e.g. my `EntityHydrator#extract(...)` is my fuctionality (it uses `parent::extract(...)` and after it does some specific sutff) and it should be tested. Once again: The problem is, that my `EntityHydrator` `is a` / extends `DoctrineObject`. That means: If I want to test it, I have to create a and `EntityHydrator` -- and creating a `EntityHydrator` needs all the dependencies of the `DoctrineObject` and causes much effort.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) in this case:

```php
namespace MyLib\Model\Entity\Hydrator;

use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\HydratorInterface;

class EntityHydrator implements HydratorInterface
{
    protected $foo;
    protected $bar;
    protected $doctrineObjectHydrator;

    public function __construct(HydratorInterface $doctrineObjectHydrator, $foo = true)
    {
        $this->doctrineObjectHydrator = $doctrineObjectHydrator;
        $this->setFoo($foo);
    }

    public function extract($object)
    {
        $extractedArray = $this->doctrineObjectHydrator->extract($object);
        $extractedArray = $this->getFoo()
            ? $this->performAdditionalFunctionality($extractedArray)
            : $extractedArray
        ;
        return $extractedArray;
    }

    // access methods for $foo and $bar

    // private/protected methods like performAdditionalFunctionality(...) and other
}
```

Now you can easily mock the original DoctrineObject hydrator and test only logic in your new hydrator.